# Plotly.Blazor Add a custom Button to Chart

Tags: c#, plotly, blazor

I'm using Plotly.Blazor and want to add a new Button to the ModeBar. Can anybody tell what the `click` Parameter expects? According to the documentation (--> https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/) for JS it needs a function, but how would that look like in C#?

This is what I got so far:

```cs
<PlotlyChart @ref="_Chart" @bind-Config="_Config"    
    @bind-Layout="_Layout" @bind-Data="_Data" 
    style="height: 70vh; min-height: 350px" />

@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private MudTheme Theme { get; set; }

    private PlotlyChart _Chart;
    private Config _Config;
    private Layout _Layout;
    private IList<ITrace> _Data;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _Config = new Config
        {
            DisplayLogo = false,
            ModeBarButtonsToRemove = new[]
            {
                "lasso2d",
                "select2d"
            },
            DisplayModeBar = DisplayModeBarEnum.True,
            ModeBarButtonsToAdd = new[]
            {
                new
                {
                    name = "TestButton",
                    icon = Icons.Material.Filled.Agriculture,
                    click = // to be filled
                }
            }  
        };
    }
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I would like to bind my own method to the `click`. For example something like this:

```
private void TestCustomIcon()
{
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance for any hint/help.